# Is there a way to type hint a class factory function which returns a subclass has multiple bases?

Tags: python-3.10

For example, we have a `class_factory(cls)` takes any class and create a subclass of both cls and Base1.

My hint only tell the mypy/pylance that it is subclss of Base1.
This results in error message of last line `a.bar()`, because the analyser
doesn't know it is also subclass of A.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

```py
class Base1(abc.ABC):
    def foo(self):
        print("Base1")


T = TypeVar("T")
def class_factory1(cls: Type[T])->Type[Base1]:
    class X(cls, Base1):
        pass
    return X

@class_factory1
class A:
    def bar(self):
        print("A")

print(isinstance(A(), Base1))
def test2(a: A):
    a.foo()
    a.bar()
```